# Java Encoding - Equivalent for sjisMS encoding in Java

Tags: java, encoding

I have to do something equivalent to `iconv -f utf8 -t sjisMS $INPUT_FILE` in Java. The command is in Unix

I am not finding any encoding with sjisMS in java. there is Shift_JIS in Java but not sjisMS. Is it Ms932 in Java?

Help me on this

Answer (score 0):

When one reads on [Shift JIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_JIS), the answer looks like yes.

You can test it with the java commandline tool native2ascii

```
native2ascii -encoding UTF-8 $INPUT_FILE tmp.txt
native2ascii -reverse -encoding Ms932 tmp.txt $OUTPUT_FILE
```

and then doing a binary compare with iconv.

Best when the input file is generated with all codes.